# Is there a way to synthetically define a serie of characters in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am currently defining a filter, that is, an array of characters to match against, like this:

```
var gFilterALPHA2="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Is there a more synthetic way to define it, eg. with a set interval of the kind

```
gFilterALPHA2 = [A-Z];
```

or

```
gFilterALPHA2 = [charCode (A) - charCode (Z)];
```

Comment: Regex! That's what you're after

Comment: Thought as much. But would the first syntax be correct in that case?

Comment: "Is there a way to synthetically define a serieS of characterss in JS.", sorry.

Comment: nope you need to enclose it in `/`.

Comment: Very good, I've got it right. Thank you.